# How to share a secret key(sensitive information) between different Android apps?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, keychain, android-keystore

How to share a secret key(sensitive information) between different Android apps?

I try to connect a Bluetooth device to several android apps. I want to use the same long term key(LTK) for all apps (AES256) and derive session keys from that LTK in each app to establish a secure communication tunnel. I use shared preference in private mode which allows the apps with the same bundle ID to access the same data, but unfortunately, the shared preference is not secure enough and the data is also available for other root access level requests. I am using the Android keystore to storing the LTK (parts of code implementation are attached) but I need to improve the solution for two scenarios:
1. Apps with the same bundle ID.
and
2. Apps with the different bundle IDs using the same SDK.

I am looking for a secure way to store the LTK in the android device which is accessible by those specific apps.

```
//-----
private boolean saveLTK(byte[] userKey)
{
        try
        {
            prefEncryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, preferenceKey);
            SharedPreferences settings = context.createPackageContext(packageNameSpace,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getSharedPreferences(KEY_PREFS_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            byte[] encUsrKey = prefEncryptCipher.doFinal(userKey);
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 + prefEncryptCipher.getIV().length + encUsrKey.length);
            byteBuffer.putInt(prefEncryptCipher.getIV().length);
            byteBuffer.put(prefEncryptCipher.getIV());
            byteBuffer.put(encUsrKey);
            byte[] encUsrKeyMessage = byteBuffer.array();
            editor.putString(encodeToString(address.getBytes(), DEFAULT), encodeToString(encUsrKeyMessage, DEFAULT));
            return editor.commit();
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | InvalidKeyException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
}

//-----
private boolean loadLTK(byte[] userKey)
{
        try
        {
            SharedPreferences settings = context.createPackageContext(packageNameSpace,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getSharedPreferences(KEY_PREFS_NAME, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String userKeyStr = settings.getString(encodeToString(address.getBytes(), DEFAULT), null);
            if (userKeyStr != null)
            {
                byte[] decUsrKey = decode(userKeyStr, DEFAULT);
                ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(decUsrKey);
                int ivLength = byteBuffer.getInt();
                byte[] iv = new byte[ivLength];
                byteBuffer.get(iv);
                byte[] decUsrKeyText = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
                byteBuffer.get(decUsrKeyText);
                prefDecryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, preferenceKey, new GCMParameterSpec(128, iv));
                byte[] userKeyStrBytes = prefDecryptCipher.doFinal(decUsrKeyText);
                if (userKeyStrBytes.length == userKey.length)
                {
                    System.arraycopy(userKeyStrBytes, 0, userKey, 0, userKeyStrBytes.length);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | InvalidKeyException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
}
```

Is there a solution similar to the Apple keychain available for Android now? (I think the Android key chain works differently. I prefer a solution like the Apple key chain to transfer the security trustworthy and challenges to the OS level.) 
OR, should I use shared preference and secure it by myself? In this regard, if I should use Android Keystore to generate and store that LTK, is the Android keystore allow me to access the same key from different apps with different bundle IDs? please describe the different options and limitations.

Answer (score 0):

In general, what is the most secure and convenient way to store pairing information and keys, as well as share them between different apps in Android?

Answer (score 0):

The best way I believe you should use a server to store and retrieve the information, you can use Firebase's Firestore with a secure authentication.
If you need it between apps you can use a **Service** with [Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL)](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl) with a query for Android 11 (API level 30)

```
<manifest package="com.example.app">
  <queries>
    <!-- Specific apps you interact with, eg: -->
    <package android:name="com.example.service" />
  </queries>
  ...
</manifest>
```